# Overriding a public variable with set

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a base class like this

```
class Base {
    public var space:Number;
}
```

which gets extended by

```
class Desc extends Base {

    override public function set space( space:Number ):void {
        //code
    } 

}
```

This doesn't compile. Say, you don't have control of the base class, what ways is there implement the same thing?

The obvious is create a function setSpace(), but this object is being embedded in an already existing system that use the `public space`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need an `override` in there before the `public`?

Comment: Yes, you do, I forgot to put that in. But it doesn't compile, "Incompatible override"

Comment: also, you may need to refer to `space` as `super.space`.  So in your `set` you'd need to set your own space variable (declared in that class) and then make a call to super.space.

Comment: You should choose another access modifier for the variable 'space', like protected, internal or private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base class should be defined that way:

```
class Base {

    // Don't use public variables. Make them private and define setters and getters 
    private var space_:Number;

    public function get space():Number {
        return space_;
    }

    public function set space(v:Number):void {
        if (space_ === v) return;
        space_ = v;
    }

}
```

And then it can be overriden that way:

```
class Desc extends Base {

    override public function set space( space:Number ):void {
        //code
    } 

}
```

**Edit:**

I missed the part where you say you don't have control over the base class. In that case, hope that `space` is defined as a getter/setter (it should be if the class is implemented properly). If not, you'll indeed have to use a function such as `getSpace` and `setSpace`.

Answer (score 3):

From [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f36.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcb):

> Class member variables that are declared using the `var` keyword cannot
>   be overridden in a subclass.

Using a setter is not an option in your case.  If you need to preserve the interface, use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class Desc {

  private var _base:Base;

  public function set space(space:Number):void {
    //code
    this._base.space = space;
  } 
}
```